# Where does settings.xml live, for tomcat 7?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, maven-tomcat-plugin

In order to use the tomcat 7 manager (or `mvn tomcat:deploy`), I need to put a settings.xml file somewhere.

The file will contain the following:

```
<server>
    <id>myserver</id>
    <username>myusername</username>
    <password>mypassword</password>
</server>
```

Where does this file go?

Does it need to be explicitly referenced somewhere?

Comment: use tomcat7:deploy.
And have a look here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336816/tomcat7-maven-plugin-tomcatmanager-status-code403-reasonphraseforbbiden][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336816/tomcat7-maven-plugin-tomcatmanager-status-code403-reasonphraseforbbiden

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `settings.xml` file is part of the [maven settings](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html) and is not specific to tomcat, though the *tomcat-maven-plugin* uses the servers defined there.

> There are two locations where a settings.xml file may live:
>
> ```
> The Maven install: $M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml
> A user's install: ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml
> ```
>
> The former settings.xml are also called global settings, the latter settings.xml are referred to as user settings. If both files exists, their contents gets merged, with the user-specific settings.xml being dominant.

You can find the exact syntax for defining servers in the [settings documentation](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Servers).